# Include un-referenced projects into nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I'm having issues creating a nuget package for a repo I've recently taken over (with no helpful input from the previous owner). The problem I'm having, is the VS nuget package creation doesn't seem to have any clear way to include other projects into the package. The way the package was built previously, was there's a base nuget package (package), that also included several other dlls from package.iOS, package.Droid, etc... But I can't figure out how to built it that way. The only other solution I can think of (which if I'm reading the nuget documentation on Microsoft correctly, it's the more correct way) is to create a separate nuget package for each of the projects, instead of including them all in the base package.

Please advise.

I am fully comfortable with creating multiple more specific nuget packages, but the people using this library are used to only downloading the base one, and it having everything they need.

I've looked into the documentation, and as far as I was able to tell, I could include referenced projects, but the base project doesn't rely on any of the other ones.

Just for reference, the project structure is similar to:

```
project
project.forms
project.iOS
project.Droid
project.macOS
project.Uwp
```

Where previous versions of the nuget built from `project` also included `project.iOS, project.Droid, project.macOS, and project.Uwp`, which in turn, depend on `project`.

Logically, to me, it seems that each of the `project.{}`s should probably have their own package, as they all may not be needed in someone's utilization of the package. Just wanted to see if there was an easy way to continue existing patterns without a load of work.

***Scratch that***
Turns out I can't make individual packages out of the `project.{}` projects through VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it, just had to make a .nuspec file, and reference that file in the `nuget pack` command.

In the .nuspec file, you need a `<files>` node with a `<file src="...thing.dll" target="lib\..." />` for each of the dll's you're needing in your project. Simple as that. Just wish there were a way to do it in the VS interface, instead of having to use a .nuspec file.